# what is this error I have in using GPS API in android?

Tags: android, gps

I have this error . even I have set the persmmissinos for GPS >>     `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />`

```
07-29 10:29:10.468: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(759): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.adhamenaya.android/com.adhamenaya.android.MapApp}: java.lang.SecurityException: Requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission
07-29 10:29:10.468: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(759):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2268)
07-29 10:29:10.468: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(759):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2284)
07-29 10:29:10.468: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(759):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:112)
07-29 10:29:10.468: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(759):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1692)
07-29 10:29:10.468: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(759):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-29 10:29:10.468: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(759):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-29 10:29:10.468: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(759):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
07-29 10:29:10.468: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(759):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-29 10:29:10.468: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(759):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-29 10:29:10.468: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(759):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
07-29 10:29:10.468: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(759):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
07-29 10:29:10.468: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(759):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-29 10:29:10.468: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(759): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission
07-29 10:29:10.468: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(759):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1234)
07-29 10:29:10.468: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(759):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1222)
07-29 10:29:10.468: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(759):     at android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy.requestLocationUpdates(ILocationManager.java:512)
07-29 10:29:10.468: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(759):     at android.location.LocationManager._requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:710)
07-29 10:29:10.468: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(759):     at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:629)
07-29 10:29:10.468: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(759):     at com.adhamenaya.android.MapApp.initMap(MapApp.java:37)
07-29 10:29:10.468: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(759):     at com.adhamenaya.android.MapApp.onCreate(MapApp.java:25)
07-29 10:29:10.468: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(759):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
07-29 10:29:10.468: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(759):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2231)
07-29 10:29:10.468: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(759):     ... 11 more
```

Edit : this is the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.adhamenaya.android"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <activity android:name=".MapApp"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    <uses-library  android:name="com.google.android.maps" />



    </application>


</manifest>
```

Comment: Please show your application manifest

Comment: @antlersoft  : see the updates

Comment: Did you try cleaning and recompiling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put your `uses-permission` tags before your `application` tag in your manifest

EDIT: for a full list of tags and what order they must appear, see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html